# Magento 2 - Symlinks not created in dev mode

Tags: css, magento2, symlink

Environment:
- Magento 2.3
- Mode: Developer
- Cache: Disabled
- empty: pub/static, except .htaccess
- empty: var/cache, var/composer_home, var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed

From there it is my understanding that if you reach the website through a browser, considering there are no static files ready to use yet, then Magento will either copy (production mode) or symlink (developer mode) the required css/js to pub/static folder for the theme used (as well as parent themes for the required files), so that the website can load properly and accordingly.

But what happens instead in developer mode, it creates a single file:

```
pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme_name/en_US/requirejs-config.js
```

Any idea why the symlinks are not generated and what's happening, why this single file requirejs-config.js is generated?

PS: we do not want to deploy static content.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command
`bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy` instead of `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Answer (score 0):

In command line :

```sh
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Clear your navigator's cache and try to reload your page.

If it still doesn't work :

```sh
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Clear your navigator's cache and try to reload your page again.

Hope it's help.

Comment: does not change anything - still generating a single file in pub/static: requirejs-config.js - as for setup:static-content:deploy -f, we do not want to use it - we do want symlinks generated instead. thanks.

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f will create symlinks for requirejs-config.js update, the final php bin/magento setup:upgrade will remove unnecessary files but keep requirejs-config.js update. This happen only with newly created requirejs-config.js files. It's the only case where i use setup:static-content:deploy in dev mode and i don't know what else to do

Comment: still does not work - the final setup:ugrade actually removes all files in pub/static/frontend folder previously deployed, leaving only the requirejs-config.js at the very same location. actually, back to the original state. is it some sort of a bug or what? thanks

Comment: It's or a bug, or something we didn't understand yet. It always have been a pain to deploy requirejs-config.js files. I hope we will learn more with your post

Answer (score -1):

try this

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US yourlang_YourLang

Comment: This will result in having to deploy again for each change. Not what you would want in developer mode